# cout and endl are undefined even though using std:: and <iostream>

Tags: cout, identifier, endl

I am trying to enter the simple "Hello World!" code, but cout and endl are undefined.

```
#include<iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

It turns out the errors: "'cout': is not a member of 'std', note: see declaration of 'std', 'cout': undeclared identifier", and the same with endl.
Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a space in the #include statement:
`#include<iostream>`

This is the correct way:
`#include <iostream>`

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```